# How to you use vue js for certain Laravel Routes and blade for other routes?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have tried searching up for this but can't seem to find an answer for this. It seems to point to if you are going to use blade then all your views must be in blade whereas if you are going to continue using vue js for your front end then every view must be in Vue.

So my question is can I use vue js for certain routes and blade for certain routes?

For an example , let's say if I have '/login' route and I would like to use Vue js for this route's front end and for '/about' route, I would like to use Laravel's blade for it's front end. Is this possible?

If yes, how to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about using Vue Router pages or just embedding VueJS on a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, create Vue components and call them from within the blade template:-

ExampleComponent.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

example.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <example-component></example-component>

@endsection
```

Comment: Wow great help ! Thanks . This is the correct solution !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @chris for the answer, however I would like to extend this answer .

Let's say if you want to register a for a new component which is in resources/js/components/AboutComponent.vue

Step 1 : Register route in web.php

```
Route::get('contact', 'TestController@contact')->middleware('auth');
```

Step 2 : Create controller and point to blade

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function contact()
    {
        return view('testing.contact');
    }
}
```

//Step 3 : Create vue component in resources/js/components/ContactComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Brought to you by Evan You</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {

        }
    } ,
    mounted() {
        console.log('Contact Component mounted.')
    }
}
</script>
```

//Step  4 Register Vue Component in resources/js/app.js

```
    /**
     * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
     * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
     * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
     */
    
    require('./bootstrap');
    
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    
    /**
     * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
     * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
     * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
     *
     * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
     */
    
    // const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
    // files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))
    
Vue.component('contact-component', require('./components/ContactComponent.vue').default);
    
    /**
     * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
     * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
     * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
     */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

// Step 5 Use this component in contact.blade.php which is located in resources/views/testing/contact.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h2>From the vue component</h2>
{{-- This is the vue component that we registered in app.js --}}
        <contact-component></contact-component>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>From the blade component</h2>
            <p>Brought to you by Taylor Otwell</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

//Step 6 Don't forget to run npm run watch

Result:

[image]

Comment: You didn't ask for a step by step guide, yes you have extended my answer however you still used it to get to the final result.

Comment: Took me some time to figure out why you commented this , I accidentally ticked my answer as the correct solution. I have ticked back your answer as the correct solution :)