# using blade views in a laravel inertia react proyect

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am wanting to use the blade views in the panel, but rendering appears in a container of the react component: AuthenticatedLayout.jsx
what I want to do is use react only in certain parts of the page, in the administrator panel do it with the blade views as any laravel project

also try to modify the dashboard:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

and i get an error:
Unable to locate a class or view for component [app-layout]

is it possible to combine blade views and react components in a Laravel/inertia project?

Comment: For that you have to call components on the blade and initialise components globally. For more possible solution for you as per my understanding is in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239263/how-to-you-use-vue-js-for-certain-laravel-routes-and-blade-for-other-routes

Comment: Check correct answer, do you mean by that?